# Insert value only when column is null

Tags: sql, if-statement, ssis, case

I have 2 different Excel sources

1. Employee Excel source
2. Sales Excel source

In my employee source I have multiple folder and in my sales source I have multiple folders as well as multiple sheets, so I had to use two data flow task and two for each loop containers for that purpose.

I need to take the ID column from my employee Excel source, if the ID column in my employee source is not available (null) only if not available in my employee source then I need to get the ID Column from my sales source, they have matching SSN, how can I achieve this?

This is my staging table

```
SELECT 
    ID, [SSN], 
    [Borrower FirstName], [Borrower LastName], 
    [Borrower Email], [Home Phone], [Cell Phone],
    [Marital Status], [Date of Birth], 
    [Current Street Address], [City], [State], [Zip],
    [YearsAtThisAddress], [Sex], [Ethnicity], [Race] 
FROM 
    [Mortgage]
```

This is my staging table, half of my data from the employee and half from sales.

Employee source has

```
[ID] ,[SSN] ,[Borrower FirstName] ,[Borrower LastName] ,[Borrower Email] ,[Home Phone] ,[Cell Phone] ,[Marital Status] ,[Date of Birth] ,[YearsAtThisAddress]
```

and SALES source has

```
[ID] ,[SSN] ,[Borrower FirstName] ,[Borrower LastName] ,[Borrower Email] ,[Home Phone] ,[Cell Phone] ,[Current Street Address] ,[City] ,[State] ,[Zip]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While I can tell you put in some effort for a first-timer, you should probably read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You may also benefit from [this helpful article on what is considered necessary for an SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 0):

You have records from two data sources merged together and part of your requirement is to know from which source the record came (whether the ID column is NULL only if from the employee source). Our only clue as to whether a record came from the "employee source" is if there are values in the columns that differ between the two ([Marital Status], [Date of Birth], [YearsAtThisAddress]), but you don't say if any of these nullable, so we must make an assumption. Assuming the value in column `[YearsAtThisAddress]` can be used to determine the record's source (`NOT NULL` means "Employee" while `NULL` means "Sales"), you could do something like this to return the corresponding "Sales" ID number for records matching on SSN when the "Employee" ID number is NULL.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ID IS NULL AND [YearsAtThisAddress] IS NOT NULL
         THEN (SELECT TOP (1) ID
                 FROM [Mortgage]
                WHERE [YearsAtThisAddress] IS NULL
                  AND ID IS NOT NULL
                  AND [SSN] = m.[SSN]
             ORDER BY ID)
         ELSE ID
    END AS ID,
    [SSN],
    [Borrower FirstName], [Borrower LastName],
    [Borrower Email], [Home Phone], [Cell Phone],
    [Marital Status], [Date of Birth],
    [Current Street Address], [City], [State], [Zip],
    [YearsAtThisAddress], [Sex], [Ethnicity], [Race]
FROM
    [Mortgage] AS m
```

Comment: My requirements is to make sure to get the ID column from employee source and if the ID column in the employee source is not available then get the ID column from Sales source, if employee source Column ID is null then take the ID value from Sales source.

Comment: @metuu This query should do that, but please explain if it fails to meet your needs.